# Visual Studio missing ; before *

Tags: c++, oop, visual-studio-2013, header-files

I'm working on Blake algorithm in Visual but I have small problem.

My `Block.h` file

```
#pragma once
#include<string>
#include<bitset>
#include<iostream> // DEBUG
#include"BlocksContainer.h"

using namespace std;

class Block {
    public:
        static void CreateBlocks(string);
        static string CreatePadding(int);
        Block(string);
    protected:
        string BlockContent;
};
```

My `BlocksContainer.h` file

```
#pragma once
#include"Block.h"

class BlocksContainer {
    public:
        int GetLength(void);
        Block* GetNBlock(int);
    BlocksContainer(Block**, int);
    protected:
        Block** Blocks;
        int Length;
};
```

I don't know why but Visual throw me `blockscontainer.h(7): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'`

I'm newby in C++ and I can't find error. In Stack I found solutions like missing `;` after class declaration, but I have semicolons.

Comment: #include"BlocksContainer.h" is the problem, it uses Block before it is declared.

Comment: @HansPassant so where I must declare this?

Comment: Your header files are mutually dependent.  This results in not having `Block` declared at the point you try to reference it.  Based on the code you've posted, you can eliminate the `#include "Block.h"` from BlocksContainer.h.

Comment: @stachu remove `#include "BlocksContainer.h"` from Block.h, and/or in main file include "BlocksContainer.h" instead of "Block.h"

Comment: `using namespace` in a header is an abomination. Also, why are you implementing your own dynamic array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont need:

```
 #include"BlocksContainer.h"
```

inside block.h, this line causes Block to be undefined inside BlocksContainer.h because it was not yet visible to compiler.

In case you really need such inter dependent headers you can declare class like this:

```
class Block;
```

after such statement you are allowed to use Block class but only in compound statements like pointers or references - that means `Block* GetNBlock(int);` would compile.

Comment: I include `BlocksContainer.h` in `Block.h` (anyway construct method error) but thanks for suggestion!